# Mod not working the way I expect

Tags: java

I'm trying to count the number of items in a scanner object which are divisible by 2.

My code looks like this:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    num = s.nextInt();
    if ((num % 2) == 0); {
        count++;
    }
}
```

For every integer in the object though, count is increasing by 1, regardless if it is divisible by 2, or not.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `if ((num % 2) == 0);` remove the `;`. Closed for typographical error.

Comment: you have a semicolon after the if

Answer (score 2):

You have a semicolon (`;`) after your if clause. That means empty code is executed if the condition is true and the code in the code block is always executed.

Answer (score 1):

The ; after the if should be omitted